# Magento2 Backend Not Add Product So give me Solution

Tags: magento2, product, error, grid, add

Magento2 Backend Not Add Product So give me Solution

Here is my

> EXCEPTION.LOG

```
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2019-04-16 13:09:25] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2019-04-16 13:09:39] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2019-04-16 13:09:53] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2019-04-16 13:10:17] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2019-04-16 13:10:59] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/ywndev/domains/dev.yeswellness.com/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
```

Here is my

> SYSTEM.LOG

```
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_area' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:25] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:38] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:09:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:10:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:10:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-04-16 13:10:59] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-16 13:10:59] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

Magenot2 Admin panel not given any error

So give me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please apply below commands
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`,`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`..

**I hope after that its working.**